# Slow down rotation speed in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have my sprite rotating, but a little too fast, here is my code, any idea how to control the speed of the rotation?

```
//enemySprite
    enemySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Asteroid.png"];
    enemySprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
    enemySprite.position = ccp(arc4random()%480, winSize.height -60);

//Rotation
    id rotate = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1 angle:360];
    id repeatRotate = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:rotate];
    [enemySprite runAction:repeatRotate];

    [self addChild:enemySprite z:5];
    [self schedule:@selector(callEveryFrame:)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make it slower by increasing its duration:

```
id rotate = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:X angle:360];
```

where you can use, e.g., 5.0 for X. This will make it 5 times slower as it currently is.